# Exception Handling error when saving to database

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Iam a newbie who needs help. When saving to a database, i get the following error:
**A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in (name of my application)**

Please help me with steps to solve this one. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the `InnerException` say?

Answer (score 1):

First chances exceptions will be shown if you have your Visual Studio settings set so that every CLR exceptions gets reported. **This will include exceptions you actually handle.**

In Visual Studio's menu, go to Debug > Exceptions and uncheck the Thrown option for Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

Of course that won't make the actual exception go away but you'll be allowed to handle it as you want:

```
try
{
    // do your query

    // commit current transaction if possible/necessary
}
catch (SqlCeException ex)
{
    // handle exception here and rollback current transaction if possible/necessary
}
finally
{
    // ensure proper disposal of any commands and connections you have
}
```

It goes without saying that you must ensure your query is properly written and that the server objects it tries to work with exists. You generally won't want to handle cases where a comma is missing or a field is not found, for instance. Exception handling must be for exceptional situations your code cannot control, like a faulted connection, a server malfunction, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you might want to check whehter your SQL query is syntactically correct.

Secondly you might want to read about how to handle exceptions in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx with try-catch statement.

A small example looks like this.

```
try
{
    // ... code which throws exception
}
catch (SqlCeException e) 
{
    // ... exception handling, e.g. logging, rolling back data,
    // telling the user something went wrong, you name it
}
```

Last but not least you might want to debug your application step by step to see what is causing the error and what the actual SQL Query is throwing the exception.

Comment: Thanks Vash, I will try that sweetheart!